# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: redis, celery, connectionexception

When ever I close the pycharm and open it and run the celery and wsgi(gunicorn) I am getting below reddis error, I have to restart redis service, in order to make my application work work again

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 264, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 627, in _connect
    raise err
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 615, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 116, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 83, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 55, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 44, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 746, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 288, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 75, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 55, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 44, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 70, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 299, in app
    raise e
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 294, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 193, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 35, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
    return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 2134, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 851, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\raraj\PycharmProjects\NoCodeAI\backend\api\views\authentication_and_authorization\authentication\authentication.py", line 133, in wrap
    redis_login_data = connect.master_redis.get_val(key="login_data_{}".format(str(user_id)))
  File "C:\Users\raraj\PycharmProjects\NoCodeAI\backend\api\connection\utility.py", line 75, in get_val
    return self.r.get(key)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\commands\core.py", line 1829, in get
    return self.execute_command("GET", name)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 533, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 270, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

what does this error mean, why is this happening, how do  I resolve this.

I am new with redis and celery, so I don't know much about it, except it's a cache holding server.Suggesting any simple, begining level documentation or any source available online could be very appriciated.

I could've checked for myself but, someone who already learnt might go through several sources and happen to find the better one, it would reduce my hustle. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Does Celery support Windows??](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows)

> Answer: No.

> Since Celery 4.x, Windows is no longer supported due to lack of resources.

> But it may still work and we are happy to accept patches.